# WebAPI app using OWIN and JWT

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, adfs, jwt

I have a front-end ASP.NET MVC 5 website that authenticates users via AD FS 3.0 using the WS-Federation protocol. Users login via the ACS login page, and all is working well on that end.

My backend is a WebAPI application that the frontend will call. They are separate realms, but both should authenticate to the same AD FS server. The difference being I'd like the WebAPI project to use JWT tokens to authenticate.

Here's the WebAPI Startup:

```
var thumbprint = "** omitted on purpose for internet eyes... **";
certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificate = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false)[0];
certificateStore.Close();

var accessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat
(
    // AllowedAudiences:
    new[] { "urn:MySolution.WebAPI" },
    //IssuerSecurityTokenProviders:
    new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[] 
    {
        new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider("https://myAdfsServer.com/adfs/oauth2/", certificate)
    }
);

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat
});

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,                     
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat
});
```

What am I missing here? I've ready MANY articles on this, and each one seems close, but just missing something. Any help is wildly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** From what I've read, JWT is not an authentication mechanism. So how should I authenticate users in my WebAPI? In my scenario, users are already authenticated on the frontend using the ACS login, however the backend is called by the frontend, so wouldn't single-sign-on from AD FS come into play here?

Answer (score 1):

OpenIdConnect is used to Authenticate users.
JwtFormat is used mainly for validating AccessTokens received using OAuthFlows.

Have a look through these samples: 
https://github.com/AzureADSamples

This may be of particular interest:
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-ManuallyValidateJwt-DotNet